# Git -- look at older version of specific file without overriding working directory version

Tags: git

Suppose I have worked on the file "foo.c" but I don't think it is ready to commit. Something is not working, so I want to open an older version of "foo.c" where that something was still working. Therefore I do

```
git checkout HEAD^ foo.c
```

But now if I want to go back by using

```
git checkout HEAD foo.c
```

the file is back to the time of the HEAD commit, not to just before I checked out the old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you executed

```
git checkout HEAD^ foo.c
```

You overwrote the changes you made to `foo.c` in your working directory.  So unless you committed or stashed those changes, they may be gone.  Next time you do this, make sure you either stash or commit your work to prevent from losing it.

One clean way to deal with this situation would be make a commit of a temporary nature:

```
git commit -m 'temporary commit'
```

Then proceed as you were:

```
git checkout HEAD^ foo.c
# work, test, etc.
```

When you wish to return back to things the way they were, you simply checkout the `HEAD`, except this time your changes will be there:

```
git checkout HEAD foo.c
```

When you have finished the feature you have in mind, you can `git add` your files, and *amend* this temporary commit:

```
git commit --amend -m 'This is the real commit'
```

Comment: A temporary commit is the cleanest way? That surprises me. I am also pretty sure I once read git checkout is a safe command.

Comment: `git checkout` is "safe" in the sense that it won't permanently affect the commits of the branch on which you execute it.  This doesn't mean it will stash away your unfinished work.  Remember, the same command is what you use to _overwrite_ a dirty file with a clean version from history.

Comment: One last thing: what makes git-stash less clean than the temporary commit? I have heard elsewhere before that git-stash should only be used rarely but don't know why

Comment: I actually agree with this, but not because `git stash` is unsafe.  I have always found that people tend to overuse stash, and they end up with a stack of dozens of old stashes, with no memory of what each one contains.  If you put down a "temporary" commit, then you will see it, and it will force you keep things clean and tidy.  So for me, it is a hygiene choice.